# Update multiple columns with the value of a single select

Tags: oracle, sql-update

Right now I got something like this:

```
UPDATE TableA
SET a  = (SELECT b FROM TableB),
    aa = (SELECT b FROM TableB)
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Is it supposed to be a correlated subquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can write:

```
UPDATE TableA
SET (a, aa) = (SELECT b, b FROM TableB);
```

Note: this assumes that TableB contains exactly one row. If not, exception will be raised.

Comment: Yes, and not widely known. Also it's worth noting that you can use similar construct in WHERE clause, e.g. `... WHERE (a, aa) IN (SELECT b, bb FROM another_table)`.

Answer (score 0):

Be careful when updating one table with the values from another, or you will update ALL rows in the target table even if you think you're only updating a few rows.  On large tables, this will be very painful (and corrupt your data).  For example:

```
update tab_x x
set (col2, col3) = (
    select col2, col3
    from tab_y y
    where x.col1 = y.col1)
-- the following part will make sure we only update rows
-- that match the join condition (x.col1 = y.col1)
-- without this part, we'd update all rows in the x table!
where exists (
    select 1
    from tab_y y
    where x.col1 = y.col1
)
```

The full example would be:

```
SQL> set display on
SQL> drop table tab_x
Table dropped.
SQL> create table tab_x
(
col1 number,
col2 varchar2(20),
col3 varchar2(20)
)
Table created.
SQL> drop table tab_y
Table dropped.
SQL> create table tab_y
(
col1 number,
col2 varchar2(20),
col3 varchar2(20)
)
Table created.
SQL> insert into tab_x values (1, 'Col2 from x','Col3 from x')
1 row created.
SQL> insert into tab_x values (2, 'Col2 from x','Col3 from x')
1 row created.
SQL> insert into tab_x values (3, 'Col2 from x','Col3 from x')
1 row created.
SQL> insert into tab_y values (1, 'Col2 from y','Col3 from y')
1 row created.
SQL> insert into tab_y values (2, 'Col2 from y','Col3 from y')
1 row created.
SQL> insert into tab_y values (9, 'Col2 from y','Col3 from y')
1 row created.
SQL> commit
Commit complete.
SQL> select * from tab_x

      COL1 COL2                 COL3                
---------- -------------------- --------------------
         1 Col2 from x          Col3 from x         
         2 Col2 from x          Col3 from x         
         3 Col2 from x          Col3 from x         

3 rows selected.
SQL> update tab_x x
set (col2, col3) = (
    select col2, col3
    from tab_y y
    where x.col1 = y.col1)
-- the following part will make sure we only update rows
-- that match the join condition (x.col1 = y.col1)
-- without this part, we'd update all rows in the x table!
where exists (
    select 1
    from tab_y y
    where x.col1 = y.col1
)
2 rows updated.
SQL> select * from tab_x

      COL1 COL2                 COL3                
---------- -------------------- --------------------
         1 Col2 from y          Col3 from y         
         2 Col2 from y          Col3 from y         
         3 Col2 from x          Col3 from x         

3 rows selected.
```